# "All users in param ids must have accepted TOS" Error

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I am trying to get my Facebook app to send me a request or notification. When I do this with `file_get_contents()` as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/), I get a "Failed to open stream" error. The code I'm using is this:

```
//after getting the access token successfully...
$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/apprequests?message='Hi'&".$app_access_token.'&method=post';
$result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
```

When I try to do the same thing through the SDK, with this code:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/MY_USER_ID/apprequests", "POST", $param);
```

I get this error:

```
All users in param ids must have accepted TOS
```

However, I have authorized the app and it has used my e-mail address.Is there a specific permission I need to request to make this work?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't completed the process of creating your app or authorizing your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the `$user_id` user doesn't use your app - you can only send app->user requests to existing users of your app

Comment: As it turns out, I thought I had added the application, but that turned out not to be the case. I had authorized the app through the javascript sdk method, which had been initialized with the app id for another one of my apps.